# Lua Matching First-Level Tags Inside <head>

Tags: nginx, lua, lua-patterns

I'm trying to get all first-level tags nested under head tag of any html response going through my reverse proxy. I'm running nginx+lua, so the solution in terms of lua pattern matching would be great...

Right now I string.sub() the inside of head tag, then iterate over the nested tags, adding them one by one to the table:

```
local headOnly = string.sub(wholeHtmlResponse, startHead, endHead)
local tags = {}
for tag in string.gmatch(headOnly, '(<[^<>]*>)') do
    tags[#tags+1]=tag
end
```

I then iterate over the "tags" table, removing all non-first-level tags. I'm not interested in any arguments or the content inside the tags, just the tags themselves.
We're talking about live requests and I'm worried this can get ugly slow if the request's head will be large enough.

So I have a few related questions:

- Is string.gmatch efficient enough?
- Is there a way/module to do this more efficiently?
- Should I consider writing my own module?

Any input appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what issue you have. If the code works alright for you, you'd rather post it at [codereview.se]

Comment: I'm not yet sure myself if this would do. Trying to evade rewriting it later, planning for the future, so to speak. Will try your suggestion!

Comment: Just FYI: Only post at code review if you are sure your code actually works. If you are unsure, please post an [MVCE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to help solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Is string.gmatch efficient enough?

You can answer this question yourself by running tests that match your use case. It's unlikely that a general answer will help you.

> Is there a way/module to do this more efficiently?

Maybe, but this again depends on what you are trying to do. If you are looking for a particular tag, it will probably be faster to search for that particular tag, instead of parsing and storing all tags and then checking. You can also abort earlier if your condition is satisfied by an early match.